# How to set an image carousel to slide automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a website and have just created an image carousel using CSS, HTML and JavaScript. I was wandering how I could get the carousel to change slide automatically every 3 seconds for example. What could I add to my code to achieve that? Here is my code.'

HTML:

```
HTML:

     ...<div class="carousel-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
        <div class="carousel-slide">
            <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="">
            <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/testpic2.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
JavaScript:

const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';


nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (counter >= carouselImages.length - 1) return;
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
counter++;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';

});
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (counter <= 0) return;
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
counter--;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';

});

carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
console.log(carouselImages[counter]);
if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone') {
carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
}
if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone') {
carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
}
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this needs a working snippet to get an answer. currently the code you have posted doesnt render anything.

Comment: Use `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. If not please provide a working snippet for validation.

```
var interval = 3000; // 1000 = 1 sec
setInterval(function(){ 

    var offset = counter%(carouselImages.length);
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * offset) + 'px)';
    counter++;

    if(offset == 0) counter = 1; // to reset counter so next and prev button should work 

}, interval);
```

Comment: works, but my third picture appears for just a moment and disappears. I changed (carouselImages.length) to (carouselImages.length - 2) but now instead of looping back to the first picture it goes back to the first one exposing the 2nd picture for a very brief moment.

Comment: each picture should show exactly 'interval' sec. Unless something else changes it.